# Plant identification in Turkey

Tags: botany, species-identification

What species is this ? It is a stinky, hairy plant. I have found it nearby a river. It had reached a height of 1 meter. Bloomed three weeks ago. Found in Turkey.

[image: rotated image]

Comment: I included the correct picture. @Oğuz İsmayil uysal - links to a webpage will not work. You should post the factual images.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like a [*Hyoscyamus niger*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyoscyamus_niger) also called *stinking nightshade*.

Comment: I knew I knew it! I thought *Chelidonium* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chelidonium but that wasn't it! Thanks! +1